# Animating differences between two paths

Tags: xaml, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I don't if what I think can be done or not but I've not found anything online so I need to ask it here.

I have two `Path` objects in my *XAML* page but I'm showing just one of them each time.

They represent 2 different emoticons, a smiling face and a sad one.

What I need to do is some kind of interpolation between the paths to animate the transition from the happy face to the sad one and viceversa.

The animation is not a static animation that is played just once but it's rather a gradual animation that follows some data in my view model.

Let's say that I've got a `TimeSpan` and the face is 100% sad at `00:00:00` while it's 100% happy at `06:00:00`.

Given this 2 paths:

path1

```
<Path Data="M32,39.704002C39.487766,39.704002 46.095413,43.433239 50.098,49.125999 44.997589,45.458061 38.76125,43.27314 32,43.27314 25.23875,43.27314 19.002413,45.458061 13.902,49.125999 17.904589,43.433239 24.512236,39.704002 32,39.704002z M41.9907,22.009001C44.746445,22.009001 46.986,24.246023 46.986,27.00515 46.986,29.763077 44.746445,32 41.9907,32 39.234856,32 36.996002,29.763077 36.996002,27.00515 36.996002,24.246023 39.234856,22.009001 41.9907,22.009001z M22.00955,22.009001C24.765379,22.009001 27.005001,24.246023 27.005001,27.00515 27.005001,29.763077 24.765379,32 22.00955,32 19.253624,32 17.014,29.763077 17.014,27.00515 17.014,24.246023 19.253624,22.009001 22.00955,22.009001z M32,4.9947796C17.110001,4.9947801 4.99547,17.109301 4.99547,32 4.99547,46.890701 17.110001,59.005199 32,59.005199 46.889999,59.005199 59.005199,46.890701 59.005199,32 59.005199,17.109301 46.889999,4.9947801 32,4.9947796z M32,0C49.673199,0 64,14.3268 64,32 64,49.673199 49.673199,64 32,64 14.3268,64 0,49.673199 0,32 0,14.3268 14.3268,0 32,0z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="276" Height="276" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
```

path2

```
<Path Data="M13.613,38.875C18.607058,42.467495 24.713106,44.60701 31.333448,44.60701 37.953793,44.60701 44.05994,42.467495 49.054001,38.875 45.13483,44.449402 38.665386,48.102001 31.333448,48.102001 24.001511,48.102001 17.532166,44.449402 13.613,38.875z M41.115601,21.551001C43.814354,21.551001 46.007,23.740988 46.007,26.44265 46.007,29.143013 43.814354,31.333 41.115601,31.333 38.417046,31.333 36.224998,29.143013 36.224998,26.44265 36.224998,23.740988 38.417046,21.551001 41.115601,21.551001z M21.551451,21.551001C24.249977,21.551001 26.442001,23.740988 26.442001,26.44265 26.442001,29.143013 24.249977,31.333 21.551451,31.333 18.852722,31.333 16.66,29.143013 16.66,26.44265 16.66,23.740988 18.852722,21.551001 21.551451,21.551001z M31.333448,4.8906832C16.753281,4.8906832 4.8913631,16.753981 4.8913627,31.333448 4.8913631,45.913017 16.753281,57.776276 31.333448,57.776276 45.913719,57.776276 57.775574,45.913017 57.775574,31.333448 57.775574,16.753981 45.913719,4.8906832 31.333448,4.8906832z M31.333448,0C48.638233,-3.5527137E-15 62.666996,14.028767 62.666996,31.333448 62.666996,48.638233 48.638233,62.666996 31.333448,62.666996 14.028767,62.666996 -3.5527137E-15,48.638233 0,31.333448 -3.5527137E-15,14.028767 14.028767,-3.5527137E-15 31.333448,0z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="276" Height="276" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
```

How can I make this work?

P.S.
Since the question is quite unusual, feel free to insult me but at least try to point me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any automatic interpolation between paths, but there are a couple of ways to approach this.

The easiest is to place both paths in the visual tree, set the Opacity of the first to 1.0 and the Opacity of the second to 0.0, then animate the opacities to change and cross-fade between the images.

The next easiest would be to create several intermediate frames and switch between them

For short animations either of these are probably pretty good. For something as long as you're talking it'd be pretty wierd.

To do a full morph you'll need to use code rather than xaml. Identify matching points in each image so you know which points represent the eyes, the nose, the mouth etc. For simple shapes like your faces you may have a one:one match between the points in the start and finish paths and can simply interpolate their coordinates.

If you can draw both the happy and sad faces with the same points in the same order, just with different locations, then it'll be pretty easy: loop through the figures and segments and create a new set with the points interpolated between happy's point and sad's point at the current time.

If the points in the two paths don't represent the same parts of the image then it's more complicated. You'll need to create a mapping between the happy points and the sad points so you know where each point moves in the new version: eyes move to eyes, mouths to mouths, etc.

Comment: I got your point and this seems the only way to do what I was trying to do, even if we're talking about something that's not easy.
I'll try your ideas later but I'll accept your answer now because it makes sense to me, thanks.